# Asynchronous logging Service in Spring Boot

Tags: asynchronous, spring-boot

I am using 1.5.6.RELEASE to create REST Api that shall store user actions in MS SQLServer database. To make this user action service asynchronous, I have configured *@EnableAsync* in my main class.

```
@EnableAsync
public class WebApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(WebApp.class, args);
  }
}

@Async
public void saveAction(ActionInfo event) {
  actionDataService.save(event);
}
```

I want to ensure that whatever happens(Server crashes, database goes down etc), user action posted by the client through Rest API service must be saved in database (may be through retry when database comes online or Application server starts again).

**Proposed Solutions**

Followings are the solutions:

1) Write AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler to handle exceptions that retries again to save user action. But if Server crashes, the user action objects shall be lost.

2) Use JMS queues to store user action. If Server crashes, the JMS queue should not be lost. It must be able to retry it when server restores. (Just an idea, does not have much knowledge about queues)

Can you please suggest?

Comment: What if the JMS queue crashes?

Comment: why make it a non blocking operation if you want to ensure it saves? If you blocked on the operation the caller will know the operation has failed and it has to retry.

Comment: Since there shall be many applications concurrently using this logging API, therefore, it has been designed to made asynchronous to improve response time. Can we just write the ActionInfo object to some binary log file, after that return OK response to the user. Another thread in parallel should read that file and then write those objects to the database. The same thing happens in Oracle database i.e. all user transactions are written to the log file as change vector, after regular intervals these changes are actually applied to the data files. In this way, the COMMIT statement is very fast.

Comment: @Cyril I agree with you that in case of JMS queue crash all messages shall be lost. I want some solution where there should be less chances of losing action messages.